# QSPI transfers in Python? (Or C, if needed?)

Tags: python, spidev

I am interfacing to an external device (NOT flash memory) which supports QSPI as well as SPI.  I plan to use the Python SpiDev package to talk to the underlying linux kernel spidev driver.

For maximum transfer rate, I'd prefer to perform QSPI transfers rather than SPI.  But.  I've not found any examples of using spidev.SpiDev() for QSPI transfers, which makes me suspect that SpiDev (and perhaps the Linux driver) doesn't support QSPI.

So it comes to this: Is there a way to perform QSPI transfers in Linux using a Python package?  If not I'll just go ahead and use SPI.